# Attach a repetitive timer to Different code bases

Tags: c++, timer, mfc

My application has 2 parts, one is a MFC based window, while the other is a C++ based code.

I need to have a timer attached to both these parts, that would trigger a behaviour at repeated intervals.

I used to be able to do this easily with `QTimer`, when I had worked with Qt.

With MFC/C++ I'm not sure what to use. Would a single `setTimer()` suffice, and how would the message handler look like in the C++ part of the code?

Kindly suggest how to attach one timer which would work with both these sections.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a single timer invoke more than one action. If you want an expired timer to result in more than one action you will have to trigger all those actions from a single timer handler.

To set up a timer you can use [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx). You get to decide whether an expired timer posts a [`WM_TIMER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644902.aspx) message or calls a callback routine instead. Either way you can trigger whichever actions you desire.

How you implement the communication is up to you. The details you provide in your question are vague. Windows does not know or care what C++ is. Saying that part of your application is C++ based code does not help much. I'm sure the MFC part is C++ based as well.

Comment: Any chance I can have both? I'd like the MFC part to handle the WM_TIMER message, and the C++ part to be done using a callback..
Otherwise I'll have to have one callback which would then internally trigger an action to the MFC part.

Comment: @user A timer can either send a `WM_TIMER` message to the window you provide or have the default message handler call the provided callback. You cannot have both, you will have to pick one. Note that your callback can be any free function or static class member.

Answer (score 0):

SetTimer only works with a window. What you refer to as the C++ part of the code cannot have a message handler unless it creates a window to receive messages.

Comment: Not actually true. You can use SetTimer from a console-based program that doesn't have a window. I.e, you _can_ pass NULL to the HWND parameter of SetTimer. You just have to setup a message-pump in your program.

Comment: That was sort of my question. If I pass on NULL as the parameter, would it work fine with both the window-based MFC, and the non-window based C++ part? And could you elaborate on the message-pump a bit, please?

Comment: The message pump is at the core of any Windows program that displays windows. It is the code that gets messages from Windows and distributes them on to parts of your program. In MFC the message pump will pass messages only to classes derived from CCmdTarget, which includes CWnd, CWinApp and CDocument. You must derive from these classes to receive a message. In the case of WM_TIMER the message will only be distributed to a class derived from CWnd.

You can use your main window to start a timer and receive WM_TIMER, then call your C++ part from that message handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying that.

Comment: @ScottMcP You should consider adding your last comment to your answer. It is very helpful to know why MFC places additional restrictions on timer handling.